# Run Alamofire request after finishing another Alamofire request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I would like to run an Alamofire request that is using the result of a previous Alamofire request as a parameter. To make it simple:

```
    //Code1
    Alamofire.request("URL", method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: ["id": id as NSString)], encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response(completionHandler: { (response) in
        let json = response.data
        do {
            print("This should be First")
            let data = try JSON(data: json!)
            let alllastmessages = data["Messages"].arrayValue
            for  i in 0..<alllastmessages.count {
                self.List.append(alllastmessages[i]["message"].stringValue)
            }}
        catch _{}
    })
    //End Code1

    //Code2
    print("This should be Last")
    for  i in 0..<List.count {
        Alamofire.request("URL2", method: .post , parameters: ["id": id as NSString] , encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response(completionHandler: { (response) in
            //Do Something
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    //End Code2
```

(This code is simplified, I'm just looking for a way to make Code1 run before Code2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way IMO is to use `DispatchGroup`, you can read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

Here's some code that works fine for me:

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()

        print("\(Date()) Start request 1!")
        Alamofire.request("https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material",
                          method: .get ,
                          parameters: [:] , encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response(completionHandler: { (response) in
                            print("\(Date()) Request 1 completed!")
                            group.leave()
                          })

        group.wait()

        print("\(Date()) Start request 2!")
        Alamofire.request("https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material",
                          method: .get ,
                          parameters: [:] , encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response(completionHandler: { (response) in
                            print("\(Date()) Request 2 completed!")
                          })
    }
```

Prints:

```
2017-12-22 18:24:45 +0000 Start request 1!
2017-12-22 18:24:47 +0000 Request 1 completed!
2017-12-22 18:24:47 +0000 Start request 2!
2017-12-22 18:24:49 +0000 Request 2 completed!
```

Comment: Thank your for your reply but this solution didn't work because it's entering the group > skipping Alamofire (since it runs last) > executing group.wait() and keeps waiting forever.

Comment: Can you show the exact code you used? I've updated my example with code that I actually executed my self, and which I saw worked fine.

Comment: Working fine now, thank you very much.
I was missing "DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to nest your calls.  You can call the 2nd call inside the callback for the first, like so:

```
Alamofire.request("URL", method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: ["id": id as NSString)], encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response(completionHandler: { (response) in
    let json = response.data
    do {
        print("This should be First")
        let data = try JSON(data: json!)
        let alllastmessages = data["Messages"].arrayValue
        for  i in 0..<alllastmessages.count {
            self.List.append(alllastmessages[i]["message"].stringValue)
        }
        //End Code1

        //Code2    
        print("This should be Last")
        for  i in 0..<List.count {
            Alamofire.request("URL2", method: .post , parameters: ["id": id as NSString] , encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).response(completionHandler: { (response) in
                //Do Something
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    //End Code2
    } catch _{}
})
```